# How did the Wall-As exit the Axiom after landing?

Tags: wall-e

We see in the film that the Wall-A robots [move along grooved tracks](https://youtu.be/3DX9QhqcQkI?t=37).

[image]

However, we see at least one [outside the ship in the end credits](https://youtu.be/hscu7cc1_2Y?t=72).

**Since they travel on rails, how did they exit The Axiom?**

Comment: Burn-E is perfectly capable of moving on his ball (hopping, primarily) without needing to sit in a rail; https://youtu.be/ppfSPzbAQYc?t=394

Answer (score 2):

In short, we don't know. As you've noted in your question, the sole view we have of them outside the ship is a single image from the end-credit sequence (below) which shows a Wall-A lifting up another robot. The Wall-A doesn't move while we're watching it, so it's possible that it's being used as a static lift, installed into place and then moved afterwards by other robots or dragged on rollers by their human slaves.

Removing them from the loading bay would be a fairly simple operation since the bay door is larger than a single robot. You'd just need to use a few dozen SECUR-T bots to lift them down.

[image]